# How to replicate the behavior of the 'which' command in POSIX-C?

Tags: c, process, posix

Is there a POSIX function that works like the `which` command? That is, I pass it a command name, and it looks in `$PATH` for executables with that name, and returns the absolute path to the command, if any.

A longer explanation: My POSIX-C application wants to launch a subprocess whose process might be called `foo` or `bar`. The first idea I had was something like (ignoring that I need the child's `stdin/stdout/stderr`):

```
 system("which foo && foo || which bar && bar");
```

I don't like this general approach because this shoves all errors concerning process invocation into the exit code of the child process and the `stdout/stderr` (which I need as binary streams in my application!).

So it looks like I need to replicate the behavior of `which` in my application code, to locate the `foo` or `bar` executable. Is there a suitable POSIX function, or do you even have a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard `fork` / `exec` pattern, but simply run `exec` twice.  If `exec` fails, you try with the other process.

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    abort();
if (pid == 0) {
    // child process
    execlp("foo", "foo", "--flag");
    if (errno != ENOENT)
        abort();
    execlp("bar", "bar", "--bar-flags");
    abort();
}
// parent process
```

This is probably the easiest way to do it, since by capturing the error code from `exec`, you can find out exactly why it failed (because `foo` does not exist).

**Alternative:** You could also implement `which` yourself in C, which may or may not be less annoying than calling `which` directly.

```
function which(file)
    path = getenv("PATH")
    for prefix in path
        if access(prefix "/" file, R_OK | X_OK)
            return prefix "/" file
        end if
    end for
    return NULL
end function
```